# Javascript closure is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, web, closures

I have inherited a code base that I need to update for my job. I'm slowly learning what they are trying to accomplish with the closure that is in place, but I am getting stuck when trying to update a part of the site that uses this functionality. I'll give a basic outline of what the code is trying to accomplish and see if anyone can help.

```
var TheObject = (function (){
    var veryLargeDependantData = {
        var1: {}, 
        var2: {}, 
        var3: [],
        //Set these variables via functions
        function1: function f1(data){...}, 
        function2: function f2(data){...}, 
        initialize: function initialize() { //set values for var1... var3}
     };

     return {initialize: veryLargeDependentData.initialize};
})().initialize();
```

Since I obviously cannot show production code on the site this will have to do. But basically the veryLargeDependentData variable is the entrance to the function. When the page loads it calls the initialize function and everything is happy. But now I need to add this to an onclick event for and older page and the firebug console says that the variable is undefined. In the other pages I am able to use it with no problem.

My question is what magic is going on that causes the closure not to be part of a callable namespace such as this. I'm a bit of a javascript nOOb so I apologize if the question sounds misguided.

```
onclick='TheObject.initialize();'
```

Comment: Can you show us the code from the `onclick` event?

Comment: `verylargeDependentData()` doesnt exist at the global scope, thus you can't call it in that manner. Only way it get's called is through `TheObject.initialize()` currently. (hard to tell due to the typos)

Comment: `verylargeDependentData` is not a function (in addition to being out of scope), what are you actually trying to do with it? Initialize it when the button is pressed instead of when the page loads?

Comment: @jerry that is exactly what I am trying to do. I want to load it as the page loads, but also on the onclick event. This is inherited code btw, so it is possible its less than pristine.

Comment: I'm still not sure what that return statement is doing there.

Comment: See my edit to your code. `TheObject` is returning an object with an `initialize` function which calls the initialize function on `veryLargeDependentData`. So, in order to call `veryLargeDependentData.initialize()`, you need to call `TheObject.initialize()` because `veryLargeDependentData` does not exist outside of `TheObject`.

Comment: This may be because I haven't done any serious JavaScript coding since college, but I don't see any benefit to using the anonymous function and `veryLargeDependantData` at all. Why not just do `var TheObject = { var1: {/*...*/}, var2: {/*...*/}, /*... ,*/initialize: function(){/*set values for var1... var3*/} };` and then call `TheObject.initialize()` directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you mean is that you want to run the `initialize` function in a click event handler, and you're currently attempting to do so like this:

```
TheObject.initialize();
```

If that's the case, the problem is that `TheObject` actually refers to the return value of `initialize`, since you called `initialize` on the return value of the immediately-invoked function expression. And the chances are that `initialize` is returning `undefined` (most likely, it has no explicit `return` statement).

To solve this, you probably want to remove the immediate call to `initalize`, which will allow you to use the line shown above both on page load and anywhere else.

Comment: I don't think he wants to call theObject initialize, he wants to initialize his object and hold the data for it inside the closure.  But he's put his return statement inside his variable declaration, + has typos.

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but the question is a bit of a mess so we can't really know what the OP is aiming for unless they update it. I think the typos are simply a result of cutting the code down drastically to post it here.

Comment: @JamesAllardice so what you are saying is that if I remove the call to the initialize function to right under the script, I should be able to call the object any time that I would like to.

Comment: I tried it. It is still saying that the object is undefined. I removed the instant initialize and then called it again with no luck.

Comment: @MichaelGuantonio It seems you also have a scope issue. Try `window.TheObject = ...` (your object must be global to be visible from the click handler).

Comment: @bfavaretto I tried that as well and didn't work. Is there any way I can place it in the 'this' object reference and get to it from there?

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure which `this` you're talking about. But what I suggested should have worked, provided you also do what this answer suggests. First, make sure TheObject is the object you expect, then fix the scope issue (if it's actually an issue).

Comment: That worked. I was referencing the wrong 'this' variable. I correctly set it in the function now to handle it via a window. Seems to be working beautifully . Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 2):

In this code, the value of `TheObject` will be whatever the `veryLargeDependentData.initialize()` method returns. If the initialize method returns nothing, `TheObject` will be undefined.

A simplified example:

```
var TheObject = (function () {
  return {
    initialize: function () { 
      // stuff happens here, but importantly, there's nothing returned
    }
  }
})().initialize();
```

You can break this down into the following order of execution:

```
// the value of step_one is a function that will return an object when it is run
var step_one = (function () {
  return {
    initialize: function () {
      // ...
    }
  }
});

// after running the function step_one, step_two will be an object
// containing one key - initialize - which is a function
var step_two = step_one();

// since initialize doesn't return anything, TheObject is set to undefined.
var TheObject = step_two.initialize();
```

You can get around this by setting `TheObject` to be the object containing the initialize method then run that method again whenever you need it.

```
var TheObject = (function () {
  return {
    initialize: function () {
    }
  }
})();

// initialize
TheObject.initialize();

// and again
TheObject.initialize();
```

**PLEASE NOTE!**

The original author may have intended for the initialize method to only be run once. Running it more than once might introduce bugs into your system!

Comment: Not bad way of explaining it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems unnecessarily complicated, I'm not sure what is gained by using the anonymous function and closure in this case. Is there any reason you can't simple do the following?

```
var TheObject = {
    var1: {}, 
    var2: {}, 
    var3: [],
    //Set these variables via functions
    function1: function(data){...}, 
    function2: function(data){...}, 
    initialize: function(){alert("initialize");}
};

var initButton = document.getElementById("initButtonName");
initButton.addEventListener("click", TheObject.initialize);
```

Note that you'd want to remove the inline event.

Comment: Since I'm new at the whole javascript thing, I was going off of the code that was written and only trying to modify its functionality. But you are right, it should follow this pattern one day in the future.